# Mapping styles when converting from Rmd to docx with RStudio and Bookdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, docx, pandoc, bookdown

I am using RStudio with the bookdown package to convert my dissertation from Rmd to docx. When I build the file, the output docx uses the 'compact' style for any ordered or unordered list, rather than the expected 'Numbered list 1' or 'List bullet 1' etc.

I tried deleting the 'compact' style from the reference.docx but then it defaulted to all lists being 'Normal'.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [Lua filter](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/lua-filters.html):

```lua
local function add_item_style (item_style)
  return function (list)
    for i, item in ipairs(list.content) do
      item = item:map(function (blk)
        return blk.t == 'Plain' and pandoc.Para(blk.content) or blk
      end)
      list.content[i] = {pandoc.Div(item, {['custom-style'] = item_style})}
    end
    return list
  end
end

OrderedList = add_item_style 'List Number'
BulletList = add_item_style 'List Bullet'
```

Save the above to a file `item-style.lua` and use it with

```yaml
---
output:
  word_document:
    pandoc_args:
      - '--lua-filter=item-style.lua'
---
```

Comment: Thank you @tarleb I was able to implement this, but I don't think it is what I am looking for (maybe I missed something...) It seems that this filter creates a new style in Word called 'MyStyle', but when I submit to a journal, they are going to want the built-in styles in Word (List Number or List Bullet). I want to map numbered lists in Rmd to the 'List Number' style that already exists in Word. Does that make sense?

Comment: Can you try with the updated code? You may have to modify the style names in the last two lines.

Comment: Maybe you can add a small example to your question. The best questions are those that are impossible to misinterpret ;)